# preg_match find multiple partial appearances of a word in a string

Tags: php, count, preg-match, preg-match-all

Any regex gurus around here? its driving me crazy.

Say I have this string:
"bookstore books Booking"

I want to count the number "books" appears in this and return the number.

Currently I have this which is not working:

```
$string = "bookstore books Booking";            
if (preg_match_all('/\b[A-Z]+books\b/', $string, $matches)) {
  echo count($matches[0]) . " matches found";
} else {
  echo "match NOT found";
}
```

On top of this the "books" inside the preg_match_all should become a $var

Anyone an idea how to count correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually much simpler, you can use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) like this:

```
$string = "bookstore books Booking";   
$var = "books";      
if (preg_match_all('/' . $var . '/', $string, $matches)) {
    echo count($matches[0]) . " matches found";
} else {
    echo "match NOT found";
}
```

Or use the function that was made for this purpose, [substr_count()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php):

```
$string = "bookstore books Booking";   
$var = "books";      
if ($count = substr_count($string, $var)) {
    echo $count . " matches found";
} else {
    echo "match NOT found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I test t thx, yes I have been looking at subtr_count but it doesn't seem to work for "bookstore" values it only counts "book" somehow